# Vehicle control in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have trouble in `opengl`. I want to rotate my vehicle while moving forward/backward. [Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIHYB.png) which shows exactly my problem. Effects of current code are in blue - after moving the car rotates over the starting location and not the current one. I want to have situation in red - in which my vehicle will rotate over current position and later move forward/backward correctly.

My current code:

```
lxr=sin(angle);
lzr=cos(angle);

xr+=speed*lxr;
zr+=speed*lzr;

totalangle+=angle

glRotatef(totalangle,0.0,1.0,0.0);
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,xr);
drawVehicle();
```

Comment: There should be an **artist** badge available on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to call translate before rotate. glRotatef rotate view matrix and it affects on current view and also matrix glTranslatef.

Answer (score 1):

From the image, I thought you are translating and then rotating, but looking at the code, I see it is not true.

So, it is obvious that you are in the `drawVehicle();` function not rendering your object in the center (0,0). You need to render it in the center, rotate and then translate.

Also, your translation is bogus. You are just translating in z direction, not in y :

```
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,xr);
```

You need to do something like this :

```
glRotatef(totalangle,0.0,1.0,0.0);
glTranslatef(0.0,yOffset,0.0);
drawVehicle(); // render around [0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to move the origin of the coordinate system too, in order to rotate your car as you wish.